# click event from javascript is not firing on button element of react rendered page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a script(a content script) in chrome extension for a react rendered page in https://akhileshcoder.com/social.

But looks like react is not entertaining changes and clicks trigger from outside.

Application context is below:

It has button like follows:

```
 <div className="form-group">
        <button className="btn btn-primary submit-btn" onClick={sendData} disabled={dataState !== API_STATE.PENDING}>Send</button>
      </div>
```

and input fields like:

```
<div className="form-group">
        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="ak-form-input-message">
          Message
        </label>
        <textarea
          className="form-input"
          id="ak-form-input-message"
          placeholder="Textarea"
          rows={3}
          onKeyUp={e => setData('message', e)}
        />
      </div>
```

I'm triggering a click event on it from console panel of developer tools like below:

```
document.querySelector('#root > div > div.page > div > div > div.message-form > div:nth-child(8) > button').click();
```

css selector for element is correct and returns valid document

[image: css selector]

When I click manually on element it works but triggering events in synchronous way it is failing to detect changes.

My guess is(not sure), is somewhere react is validating the events are fired externally or not, if it is the situation(even if it is not) how to mimic events externally.

- Below is the json dump of events I'm firing programmatically.

```js
    [ 
    {
        "id": "ak-form-input-name",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "text",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(1) > input",
        "textValue": "fqwefwefwe",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-name",
        "value": "fqwefwefwe",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keydown"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-name",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "text",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(1) > input",
        "textValue": "fqwefwefwe",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-name",
        "value": "fqwefwefwe",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keyup"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-name",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "text",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(1) > input",
        "textValue": "fqwefwefwe",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-name",
        "value": "fqwefwefwe",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "change"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-email",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "email",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2) > input",
        "textValue": "qwqwfqwfqwf@aqwf.qwfqef",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-email",
        "value": "qwqwfqwfqwf@aqwf.qwfqef",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keydown"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-email",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "email",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2) > input",
        "textValue": "qwqwfqwfqwf@aqwf.qwfqef",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-email",
        "value": "qwqwfqwfqwf@aqwf.qwfqef",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keyup"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-email",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "email",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2) > input",
        "textValue": "qwqwfqwfqwf@aqwf.qwfqef",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-email",
        "value": "qwqwfqwfqwf@aqwf.qwfqef",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "change"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-mob",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "tel",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(3) > input",
        "textValue": "feqfwefwefwe",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-mob",
        "value": "feqfwefwefwe",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keydown"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-mob",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "tel",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(3) > input",
        "textValue": "feqfwefwefwe",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-mob",
        "value": "feqfwefwefwe",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keyup"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-mob",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "INPUT",
        "type": "tel",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(3) > input",
        "textValue": "feqfwefwefwe",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-mob",
        "value": "feqfwefwefwe",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "change"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-message",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "TEXTAREA",
        "type": "textarea",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(5) > textarea",
        "textValue": "efwefwefwef",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-message",
        "value": "efwefwefwef",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keydown"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-message",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "TEXTAREA",
        "type": "textarea",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(5) > textarea",
        "textValue": "efwefwefwef",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-message",
        "value": "efwefwefwef",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "keyup"
      },
      {
        "id": "ak-form-input-message",
        "className": "form-input",
        "tagName": "TEXTAREA",
        "type": "textarea",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(5) > textarea",
        "textValue": "efwefwefwef",
        "selector": "#ak-form-input-message",
        "value": "efwefwefwef",
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "change"
      },
      {
        "id": "",
        "className": "btn btn-primary submit-btn",
        "tagName": "BUTTON",
        "type": "submit",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(7) > button",
        "textValue": "",
        "selector": "button.btn.btn-primary.submit-btn",
        "value": null,
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "mousedown"
      },
      {
        "id": "",
        "className": "btn btn-primary submit-btn",
        "tagName": "BUTTON",
        "type": "submit",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(7) > button",
        "textValue": "",
        "selector": "button.btn.btn-primary.submit-btn",
        "value": null,
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "mouseup"
      },
      {
        "id": "",
        "className": "btn btn-primary submit-btn",
        "tagName": "BUTTON",
        "type": "submit",
        "domPath": "body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(7) > button",
        "textValue": "",
        "selector": "button.btn.btn-primary.submit-btn",
        "value": null,
        "TRIGGER_TYPE": "click"
      }
    ]
```

- below is code I'm using in extension to play events on content script:

[image: replayEvents]

Here is screenshot, when data is getting filled but I guess click and change events are not firing inside react context.

[image: https://akhileshcoder.com/social]

Comment: Where is your code that is failing to cause clicks on buttons?

Comment: Hi @James, thanks! Attached code triggering events with the question

Answer (score 0):

Directly invoking the `onClick` handler:
Instead of triggering a click event on the button element, you can try directly invoking the onClick handler function associated with the button. For example:

**Javascript:**

```
const buttonElement = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');
buttonElement && buttonElement.onclick();
```

---

Comment: I guess It's not `onclick()` it's .click(),
I tried both `.click()`, `e.dispatchEvent(new Event(evName));`
None was helpful